# I want to allow users to search by certain attribute values, for example color and brand

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, module

I am trying to programatically retrieve a list of products using name attribute. I want to allow users to search by certain attribute values for example color and brand using ajax.

Here is my code

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array(
    'name' => 'frontend'
));
$product_search = $_REQUEST['term'];
if ($product_search) {
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToFilter(array(
        array(
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'like' => '%' . $product_search . '%'
        )
    ))->addAttributeToSelect('price')->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')->joinField('qty', 'cataloginventory/stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left');

    $imageHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/image');
    foreach ($productCollection as $_product) {
        $thumbail_src = "";
        $url          = $_product->getProductUrl();
        $data         = ' <div class="autocomplete-image"> <img src="' . $imageHelper->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(50, 75) . '"></div> <div class="top">' . $_product->getName() . '</div><li><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="price">' . $_product->getPrice() . '</span></li> ';
        $respones[]   = array(
            'id' => $_product->getId(),
            'name' => $_product->getName(),
            'data' => $data,
            'price' => $_product->getPrice(),
            'qty' => $_product->getQty()
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($respones);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to update this code and if you want to filter with new attribute code than add new **attribute code** into ***$attrArray*** variable.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array(
    'name' => 'frontend'
));
$product_search = $_REQUEST['term'];
$attrArray = $arrayName = array('color','brand');
if ($product_search) {
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name','brand','color')->addAttributeToSelect('price')->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')->joinField('qty', 'cataloginventory/stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left');
    $searchArray = array(
        array(
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'like' => '%' . $product_search . '%'
        )
    );
    foreach ($attrArray as $key => $code) {
        $options = getAttrOptions($code);
        $optionId=null; 
        if($options){
            foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
                if(strtolower($value['label']) == strtolower($product_search)){
                    $searchArray[] = array(
                            'attribute' => $code,
                            'eq' => $value['value'] 
                        )
                    ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($searchArray);

    $imageHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/image');
    foreach ($productCollection as $_product) {
        $thumbail_src = "";
        $url          = $_product->getProductUrl();
        $data         = ' <div class="autocomplete-image"> <img src="' . $imageHelper->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(50, 75) . '"></div> <div class="top">' . $_product->getName() . '</div><li><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="price">' . $_product->getPrice() . '</span></li> ';
        $respones[]   = array(
            'id' => $_product->getId(),
            'name' => $_product->getName(),
            'data' => $data,
            'color' => $_product->getColor(),
            'price' => $_product->getPrice(),
            'qty' => $_product->getQty()
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($respones);
}
function getAttrOptions($code){
    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute($code);
    if ($attr && $attr->usesSource()) {
        return $attr->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    }
}
?>
```